# Add custom function to WC_Order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I just created a custom plugin for WooCommerce, so I can add a new manual payment method, so far I already can get it running. But the problem I face right now is I get a 0 value.

I create a class that extend `WC_Order()`, here is the code

```
class WC_Order_Extender extends WC_Order {

    public function __construct( $order_id ) {

        parent::__construct( $order_id );

        $this->data['price_in_btc'] = 0.0;

        print_r($this->data);
    }

    public function get_price_in_btc() {

        return $this->get_prop( 'price_in_btc' );
    }

    public function set_price_in_btc( $value ) {

        $this->set_prop( 'price_in_btc', wc_format_decimal( $value, 7 ) );
    }
}
```

and here is when the function is called

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {

    //$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_extended = new WC_Order_Extender( $order_id );

    // get_price_in_btc() always return 0 in thankyou.php page
    $order_extended->set_price_in_btc( $this->get_bitcoin_rate( $order_extended->get_total() ) );

    // Mark as On-Hold (We're waiting for the payment)
    $order_extended->update_status( 'on-hold', __( 'Awaiting for manual BTC payment ', 'wc-manual-btc-gateway' ) );

    // Reduce item stocks
    wc_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id );

    // Clean up the cart
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();

    // Return thank you redirect
    return array(
        'result'    => 'success',
        'redirect'  => $this->get_return_url( $order_extended )
    );
}
```

Here is the code to call `price_in_btc` value in `thankyou.php` page

```
$extended_order = new WC_Order_Extender( $order->get_id() );

echo $extended_order->get_price_in_btc(); // Always return 0
```

at first I thought because it return `0.00*****` coin, so it rounded to `0`, so I thought it's a problem with the decimal, so I add `wc_format_decimal` when set the prop, but it's still return as 0, even the actual return bitcoin price is 0.0004***.

Please help, where is the mistake I made in my code?

**EDIT**

the data that stored in the extended `$order`

[image]

**EDIT 2**

The prove that `price_in_btc()` function is returning a value **the console.log()**

[image]

and here is the code

```
public function get_bitcoin_rate( $total_price ) {

    $cUrl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array( $cUrl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/IDR.json',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache"    
        )
    ) );

    $data = json_decode( curl_exec( $cUrl ), true );

    $err = curl_error( $cUrl );

    curl_close( $cUrl );

    echo "<script>console.log( '" . wc_format_decimal( $total_price / $data['bpi']['IDR']['rate_float'], 7 ) . "' );</script>";

    return $total_price / $data['bpi']['IDR']['rate_float'];
}
```

and here is with the `wc_format_decimal()`

[image]

**EDIT 3**

I add `$order_extended->save();` below the `set_price_in_btc()`:

```
$order_extended->set_price_in_btc( $this->get_bitcoin_rate( $order_extended->get_total() ) );
$order_extended->save();
```

But it's still return a `0` value. Please help I don't know what to do.

Comment: 2nd parameter is "Number of decimal points to use", So can you try with `wc_format_decimal( $value,7 )`

Comment: @SudharshanNair I just add the decimal points, but still return a 0 value, but thanks :D

Comment: Are you sure the rest of it is working, rather than the rounding being the issue? For example, where is the function `process_payment()` being used? `$this` in `$this->get_bitcoin_rate()` suggests that it is part of a class, is it? Is this function working properly? If not, I would imagine that it would return false, which is easy to confuse for 0.

Comment: @PeterHvD is correct, First try to print `wc_format_decimal( $value, 7 )` directly in `set_price_in_btc` function to see, whether the value is giving correct number or not

Comment: Hi please check my edit, the function is working @PeterHvD

Comment: @SudharshanNair please check my editted question

Comment: @SudharshanNair and the set_price_in_btc() is working as well. so why does this happening? is it because woocommerce prop can't accept decimals number?

Comment: Use `number_format function instead`.`$res= '0.00014111725937536';
echo number_format($res,7);`

Comment: @SudharshanNair I already tried that as well, but it's still showing as 0 after `set_prop()` I don't know why, so now I tried to save it as string, hope it's working

Comment: Are you getting correct Value here? `$this->get_bitcoin_rate( $order_extended->get_total()`

Comment: @SudharshanNair yes it's getting the correct value, everything works just fine, only the problem with set the data to `price_in_btc` that I can't found where is the problem, or what should I write instead `set_prop()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176409/discussion-between-sudharshan-nair-and-khrisna-gunanasurya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wandering around across the google, and finding for some answer, finally I kinda give up with my curent coding, delete the `order extender` and then create a really-really simple codes, that I don't know is this OK or not.

For anyone that having some troubles the same with me and didn't found the answer, use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'wc_add_custom_meta_order', 20, 2 );

function wc_add_custom_meta_order( $order, $data ) {

    $order->update_meta_data( '_price_in_btc', $data );
}
```

For inserting the new custom meta data

```
$price_in_btc = number_format( $this->get_bitcoin_rate( $order->get_total() ), 5 );

before_checkout_create_order( $order, $price_in_btc );
```

this solves my problem very well even though it's kinda the stupid way to do it, and in the thankyou.php page I just need to call the meta directly using `get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_price_in_btc', true )`

Hope this answer useful for you! Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried to replace `wc_format_decimal` with `number_format`?

```
public function set_price_in_btc( $value ) {

        $this->set_prop( 'price_in_btc', number_format( $value, 7 ) );
    }
```